# Jquery issue in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hello I m new in reactjs. I want to know how to call external jquery function which is added in client index.html (main file) in reactjs.
I want to run this file when i submit the form then details goes to this file and getch the data and return back with json details

Answer (score 0):

```html
use this in js file
module.exports = {
  function_name : function_name
}

then include this file in reactjs 
use defined function name and call it
function(parms1, parms2);
```